# How to ignore js file from webpack config in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My webpack config file shows error `Sitemap is not function`, If I ignore css file it's working fine, if I ignore js file it display this error. How to ignore js file. Could you please check my config file below.
Error:

```
> babel-node src/sitemap-builder.js

F:\react\test\live\testserver\src\sitemap-builder.js:16
new Sitemap(router).build("http://localhost:3000/").save('./public/sitemap.xml');
^

TypeError: Sitemap is not a constructor
```

webpack config file:

```
require("babel-register")({
    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
  });
  require.extensions['.scss'] = () => {
    return;
  };
  require.extensions['.css'] = () => {
    return;
  };
  require.extensions['.js'] = () => {
    return;
  };

  const router = require('./Routes').default;
  const Sitemap = require('react-router-sitemap').default;
  (
     new Sitemap(router)
        .build("http://localhost:3000/")
        .save('./public/sitemap.xml')
  );
```

Comment: could you please help me??

Answer (score 0):

Check if anything happens by using this

```
const Sitemap = require('../').default;
```